# Finding a tag in text and prepend with code

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'd like to search for this start of iframe tag in text (articles from a database)

```
<iframe
```

and replace it to this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe
```

I've tried str_replace (but this one works from left to right) and preg_replace kills the entire code.

to be more precise, this is what needs to be done:

```
$article = str_replace("<iframe scr", "<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class=\"embed-responsive-item\" scr", $article);
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What attribute is `scr`?

Answer (score 0):

Watch your single and double quotes:

```
$article = str_replace('<iframe scr', '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class=\"embed-responsive-item\" scr', $article);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is still not working.

Comment: In your original document, do you have `<iframe scr`?  If you do, the line above should replace it.